# How likely would a character be to identify a Futura morph?

Tags: eclipse-phase

I have a player who is playing a member of the Lost generation and since we're just starting is required to be in a Futura morph.  Part of the backstory I've laid out for the game is that the characters have previously gatecrashed together so they've worked together.  My player wants his history as a member of the Lost to be secret but I'm unsure how well he could do that while in a Futura morph.

So my question(s) are this: what is the likelihood that the average person would know a Futura morph on sight?  Would their muses be able to identify them?  The generation is fairly notorious.  In addition what skills would matter in identifying a Futura morph/Lost generation ego?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Is it possible?**

Yes. [Jack Graham](http://www.eclipsephase.com/comment/3353#comment-3353) answered this very question on the Eclipse Phase forum.

**How**

Perception check, interest (the lost), or academics (biology/morphs) seems to be the most straight forward way of handling it.